Using 'org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi' how to hide Paths/Services?
We are using org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi in a JAX-RS application and we have applied the @Schema(hidden = true) annotations both at the class level and at the Path/service level but the services are not hidden in the generated OpenAPI file so they are visible in the Swagger UI.  How can we make them not be included in the OpenAPI file?
We are using
microprofile.openapi version 3.1.1 with Quarkus version 3.12.3

We tried using the @Schema(hidden = true) annotation and we expected the path/service to be hidden.

It turns out with microprofile.openapi @Schema(hidden = true) only works at the class level so everything is hidden.  If you want to hide just certain paths then use hidden = true in the @Operation per endpoint.
